# Neo4J: How can I find if a path traversing multiple nodes given in a list exist?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jrestclient

I have a graph of nodes with a relationship *NEXT* with 2 properties sequence (*s*) and position (*p*). For example:

```
N1-[NEXT{s:1, p:2}]-> N2-[NEXT{s:1, p:3}]-> N3-[NEXT{s:1, p:4}]-> N4
```

A node N might have multiple outgoing *Next* relationships with different property values.

Given a list of node names, e.g. [N2,N3,N4] representing a sequential path, I want to check if the graph contains the nodes and that the nodes are connected with relationship *Next* in order.

For example, if the list contains [N2,N3,N4], then check if there is a relationship *Next* between nodes N2,N3 and between N3,N4.

In addition, I want to make sure that the nodes are part of the same sequence, thus the property *s* is the same for each relationship *Next*. To ensure that the order maintained, I need to verify if the property *p* is incremental. Meaning, the value of *p* in the relationship between N2 -> N3 is **3** and the value *p* between N3->N4 is (3+1) = **4** and so on.

I tried using APOC to retrieve the possible paths from an initial node N using python (library: neo4jrestclient) and then process the paths manually to check if a sequence exists using the following query:

> q = "MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.name = 'N' CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(n {relationshipFilter:'NEXT>', maxLevel:4}) YIELD path RETURN path"
>
> results = db.query(q,data_contents=True)

However, running the query took some time that I eventually stopped the query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a bit tough.

First, pre-match to the nodes in the path. We can use the collected nodes here to be a whitelist for nodes in the path

Assuming the start node is included in the list, a query might go like:

```
UNWIND $names as name
MATCH (n:Node {name:name})
WITH collect(n) as nodes
WITH nodes, nodes[0] as start, tail(nodes) as tail, size(nodes)-1 as depth
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {whitelistNodes:nodes, minLevel:depth, maxLevel:depth, relationshipFilter:'NEXT>'}) YIELD path
WHERE all(index in range(0, size(nodes)-1) WHERE nodes[index] = nodes(path)[index])
// we now have only paths with the given nodes in order
WITH path, relationships(path)[0].s as sequence
WHERE all(rel in tail(relationships(path)) WHERE rel.s = sequence)
// now each path only has relationships of common sequence
WITH path, apoc.coll.pairsMin([rel in relationships(path) | rel.p]) as pairs
WHERE all(pair in pairs WHERE pair[0] + 1 = pair[1])
RETURN path
```

Comment: Thank you @InverseFalcon. When I add whitelistNodes:tail the query doesn't return any results while removing it does, any idea why?  Also there might be multiple paths between nodes with the same sequence, as a result the line `WITH path, apoc.coll.pairsMin([rel in relationships(path) | rel.p]) as pairs` returns a list of list of positions. For example: [["4","5"],["5,"1]]     -    [["77","78"],["78,"79]]    -  [["77","78"],["78,"74] , how can I edit the query to loop though this list and return only the paths with consecutive positions?

Comment: If no results are returned, then that should mean that there are no possible paths of `depth` length including only those nodes. You could try using `whitelistNodes:nodes` instead, if you aren't using the latest APOC version then it won't be skipping the whitelist filtering on the start node.

Comment: This WHERE clause should be doing that consecutive filtering for you: `WHERE all(pair in pairs WHERE pair[0] + 1 = pair[1])`. That should ensure for each adjacent pairing of positions, that the first position of the pair +1 = the next position.

Comment: Using `whitelistNodes:nodes` solved it as well as p was a string so I modified the where clause to WHERE all(pair in pairs `WHERE toInt(pair[0]) + 1 = toInt(pair[1]))` and the query now works. Many thanks, I appreciate it.